# Difficulty with Equivalence Proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm having difficulty proving that p ↔ q ≡ (p → q) ∧ (q → p). I've tried breaking it down from both sides, but nothing is clicking yet. So far, I believe my best attempt was with p ↔ q and goes something like this:

p ↔ q

(p ∧ q) ∨ (¬p ∧ ¬q) (Law of Equality)

(p ∧ q) ∨ ¬(p ∧ q) (DeMorgan 2)

¬(p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∧ q) (Symmetry)

(p ∨ q) → (p ∧ q) (Implication)

From here I'm stuck as to where I should go next or even if I'm in the right direction in the first place. Any help and advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since there are only two propositional variables, it is advisable to make use of truth tables.

Comment: @APCorreia -- Depending on what level the class is, truth tables might not actually be enough. If OP's professor wants a formal derivation, then a truth table argument shows that such a derivation _exists_, but doesn't tell us what it is. I don't think that it matters in this case, but this misconception is a pet peeve of my inner logician.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor You would be right. I've mapped it out on a truth table already, but I do need a formal proof of the equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

The second step gives you a disjunction of conjunctions.  You want a conjunction of conditionals -- and conditionals are equivalent to certain disjunctions.

So the next step(s) should be distribution to obtain a conjunction of disjunctions.

$${p\leftrightarrow q\\(p\wedge q)\vee(\neg p\wedge\neg q)\\(p\lor(\neg p\wedge \neg q))\wedge(q\vee(\neg p\wedge\neg q))\\(p\vee\neg p)\wedge(p\vee\neg q)\wedge(q\vee\neg p)\wedge(q\vee\neg q)\\~~\vdots\\(p\to q)\wedge(q\to p)}$$

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to show the equivalence starting with the expression on the right-hand side.

Using another standard notation with $+$ for $\vee$, $\cdot$ for $\wedge$, $0=F$, $1 = T$ and $p'$ for $\neg p$, you get

\begin{eqnarray*}(p\rightarrow q)(q\rightarrow p)
& = & (p'+q)(q'+p)\\
& \stackrel{distributivity}{=} &  p'q' + p'p+qq'+qp \\
& \stackrel{p'p=q'q=0}{=} &  p'q'+0 + qp \\
& \stackrel{a+0 = a}{=} & p'q'+pq\\
& = & p\leftrightarrow q
\end{eqnarray*}